# struts error upon deploying the application on tomcat 5.5

Tags: java, tomcat, struts2

I am getting the below error upon deploying the web application on tomcat 5.5 , Please advise which jar is missing in my class path so that I can add the required jar

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/web/startup/TilesListener
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well a little bit of googling says that the this class is in:

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tiles/tiles-servlet/2.2.2/tiles-servlet-2.2.2.jar

this jar. If it still not works try googling somethink like: `org/apache/tiles/web/startup/TilesListener jar`

Answer (score 0):

Use [findjar.com](http://www.findjar.com) for such situations where you don't know which jar to add to classpath.

In your case the system is not able to load the definition of TilesListener. So, probably you want to add that class to your classpath. For that the related jar can be found at, http://www.findjar.com/index.x?query=org%2Fapache%2Ftiles%2Fweb%2Fstartup%2FTilesListener
Just click on the [class] link.

Answer (score 0):

Add This jar file to library packages if you are using any ide or else set classpath of the class

http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener